# How to evaluate a line integral when the curve is oriented clockwise

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the line integral $\int_{C}^{} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx +\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ where C is any circle centered at the origin with a clockwise orientation.

I can set up the integral fine. My problem is with the orientation of the curve.

If the curve is oriented clockwise the shouldn't the bounds of the integral for the paramterisation go like $\int_{0}^{-2\pi}$? Because that would mean we start and $\theta = 0$ and then travel clockwise around until we reach $\theta = 0$ again. Also is this equivalent to $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$?

Comment: Yes to first question. No you cant parametrize it from  $-\pi$ to $\pi$, that would be counterclockwise

Comment: You can always compute the integral for the counterclockwise orientation, and change the sign once computed.

Comment: So, the answer to the line integral is then $-2\pi$?

Comment: You could use parameterization $(\cos \theta, -\sin \theta)$ and go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Reversing the orientation just reverses the sign of the outcome, as Demetri said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the ordinary substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ with $\theta$, as you said, running the limits backwards from $0$ to $-2\pi$.

$$\int_0^{-2\pi}$$

Alternatively, you could make the substitution $x=r\cos(-\theta) \equiv r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin(-\theta) \equiv -r\sin\theta$ and run the limits as normal, i.e. from $0$ to $2\pi$.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}$$